# Implementation of comp

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to understand how this function work, which is an implementation of `comp` (from the chapter "Functional Programming" in the book [Clojure for the Brave and True](http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/)):

```
(defn two-comp
  [f g]
  (fn [& args]
    (f (apply g args))))
```

The idea is that it takes two functions and apply them to args. What I don't understand is how the args reach the anonymous function, since they are not entered as arguments to `two-comp`? How can be `two-comp` used this way?

Comment: For `g` that takes just one argument, `(defn two-comp [f g] (fn [x] (f (g x))))` *returns a function* that invokes `f` upon the result of invoking `g` upon its argument. As [@mipadi explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27234615/1562315), The `two-comp` in the question just modifies this so that `g` can have any number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`two-comp` returns an anonymous function, which in turn takes `args`. Look at the body of `two-comp`:

```
(fn [& args]
  (f (apply g args)))
```

`fn` creates a function, and that function definition follows. The return value of `fn` is what is returned from `two-comp`.